# How to embed a DLL into a DLL?

Tags: c++, dll

I managed to create a program in C++ / Visual Studio 2010, 2017. And now I have to embed a DLL (`B.dll`) inside of another DLL (`A.dll`).

I succeed in executing another program (`C.exe`) that uses `A.dll`. But I don't know how to embed a DLL into a DLL.

Is it possible ? If it is possible, what should I do?

I have solutions for `A.dll`, `B.dll`, `C.exe`.

[image]

Comment: You should explain what problem you are trying to solve by embedding B into A. You are most likely heading in the wrong direction.

Comment: Well... I have been released 'A.dll' to any user. So, I have to get the 'A.dll' after solution build only one. A.dll is need B.dll because of sentry functions. Just embed and get the only one A.dll after build.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Which part of your application depends on B?

Comment: B.dll depends on A.dll. There must be a B.dll in the folder where the executable file (c.exe) occurs to operate A.dll. But I want to insert B.dll into A.dll.

Comment: If I correctly understand, you want to hide B. I do not see the point of this (what's wrong with providing both dlls?!), but if you really must, follow Remy’s advice. See here an example: [https://blog.kowalczyk.info/article/zy/embedding-binary-resources-on-windows.html](https://blog.kowalczyk.info/article/zy/embedding-binary-resources-on-windows.html)

Comment: @JuHyeonLee it sounds more like you want to compile `B.dll`'s actual code statically into `A.dll`'s code, not simply embed `B.dll` as-is into `A.dll`. That is two completely different scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you truly want to embed `B.dll` *inside* of `A.dll`, you can define `B.dll`  as a *resource* of `A.dll` via an [`.rc` script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/resource-files-visual-studio) in `A.dll`'s project. Then you can use `B.dll` at runtime by first using `(Find|Load|Lock)Resource()` to access the bytes for `B.dll`'s resource and writing them to a tempory file using `(Create|Write)File()` before then loading that file with `LoadLibrary()`.

Comment: Thank you. Could i ask for detail to make to .rc script ?

Comment: Is it exist the B.dll method in script?

Comment: @JuHyeonLee did you read the documentation I linked to in my answer?

Comment: oh i miss it linked, Sorry. I read it and will reply comment. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

If you mean linking by 'embed', You can use the same `.lib` file for your `B.dll` to link with `A.dll` as you did with `C.exe`.

Comment: Thank you to comment. C.exe is not include A.dll. Because Dynamic Linking, and it needs A.dll in their directory. But I want to A.dll include B.dll.

Comment: You build `B.dll` to get `B.lib`. You link `B.lib` in your `A.exe` project, so your `A.exe` depends on `B.dll`. Is that right? Same thing goes to `A.dll`. It doesn't matter it's static or dynamic linking.